# Does $\lim_{ n \rightarrow \infty}b_n \sum_{ k = 1 }^n a_k =L<\infty$ imply $ \lim_{ n \rightarrow \infty}b_n \sum_{ k = 1 }^n a'_k =L. $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

Asumme that $(b_n)_{ n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $(a_n)_{ n \in \mathbb{N}}$ are **non-negative** sequences such that
$$
\lim_{ n \rightarrow \infty}b_n \sum_{ k = 1 }^n a_k =L<\infty.
$$

> If $(a'_n)_{ n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence obtained from an arbitrary re-enumeration of $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, is it true that
> $$
> \lim_{ n \rightarrow \infty}b_n \sum_{ k = 1 }^n a'_k =L?
> $$

For example, if
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k = \tilde{L} <\infty,
$$
then it is known that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a'_k = \tilde{L}.
$$
Does a similar result hold for the case mentioned above? If necessary, one may assume that $b_n \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: What about the case $b_n =1$ for all $n$?

Comment: Then the result is true, since $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ are non-negative by assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have given this some thought since my reply yesterday, and it turns out, with the conditions given in your question, I could find a counterexample where this doesn't hold:

I will number the terms starting from $0,1,2,\dots$, and let

$$b_n := \frac{1}{2^n} \\
a_0 := 1; \quad \forall n \ge 1: a_n := 2^{n-1}$$

Obtaining the sequences

$$(b_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}_0}= \left(1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{8}, \frac{1}{16}, \frac{1}{32}, \frac{1}{64}, \dots\right) \\
(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}_0}=(1,1,2,4,8,16,32,64\dots)$$

Where $b_n \to 0$.

The reordered $a'_n$ sequence will be defined the following way: Let's swap every consecutive term in $a_n$, giving us:
$$(a'_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}_0}=(1,1,4,2,16,8,64,32\dots)$$

Then let us define the summation series as two new sequences:

$$s_n := \sum_{k=0}^n a_k \qquad s'_n := \sum_{k=0}^n a'_k$$

And this table summarizes the results:

\begin{array} {|r|r|}\hline n & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\ \hline b_n & 1 & \frac{1}{2} &  \frac{1}{4} &  \frac{1}{8} &  \frac{1}{16} &  \frac{1}{32} &  \frac{1}{64} &  \frac{1}{128} \\ \hline a_n & 1 & 1 & 2 & 4 & 8 & 16 & 32 & 64 \\ \hline s_n & 1 & 2 & 4 & 8 & 16 & 32 & 64 & 128 \\ \hline a'_n & 1 & 1 & 4 & 2 & 16 & 8 & 64 & 32 \\ \hline s'_n & 1 & 2 & 6 & 8 & 24 & 32 & 96 & 128 \\ \hline b_n \cdot s_n & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline b_n \cdot s'_n &  1 & 1 & \frac{3}{2} & 1 & \frac{3}{2} & 1 & \frac{3}{2} & 1 \\ \hline  \end{array}

So

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} b_n \sum_{k=0}^n a_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} b_n s_n = 1 \\
\lim_{n \to \infty} b_n \sum_{k=0}^n a'_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} b_n s'_n = \not \exists$$

While the first sequence tends to $1$ (is constant $1$), the second sequence doesn't even have a limit, as it constantly alternates between $1$ and $\frac{3}{2}$.

My hypothesis is that $s_n = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k$ needs to **also** be convergent for this to be true.

Answer (score 0):

**My answer doesn't consider the $b_n$ factors, but it still might be somewhat helpful.**

What you have stumbled upon is called [Absolute Convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_convergence).

For series that are absolutely convergent, your statement holds. The opposite to absolutely convergent series is called "conditinally convergent". An example is the alternating harmonic series $1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{6} + \dots$, which converges to $\ln(2)$. However its rearrangement $1 + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{7} - \frac{1}{4} + \dots$ converges to $\frac{3}{2} \ln{2}$.

I recommend [this amazing video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U0w0f0PDdPA&t=0s) by Morphocular that explains how this can be possible.

Comment: I don't see how this deals with the $b_n$ factors in the question. In particular, we don't know that $\sum_na_n$ converges.

Comment: We can substitute $\sum_k a_k$ to $\sum_k a'_k$ at every single step, because they are equal.

Comment: @DanielP could you clarify on how to do deal with $b_n$ exactly?

Comment: After some thought it seems I might have misunderstood your problem, I thought the arbitrary re-enumeration only occurs in $\{1,\dots,n\}$, making a simple substitution possible. So this isn't a full answer. Nonetheless, absolute convergence is definitely necessary here.